# What PCI-Express graphics cards are first generation?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I want to purchase a new graphics card for my Asrock Motherboard, I asked Asrock support which brand should work for my mobo. The response was somewhat confusing:

> The Motherboard Asrock G41M-VS3 R2.0 has a 16X PCI-Express slot first generation, and works well with this current generation either be ATI or NVidia, do not install a second generation card because it won't be detected.

I have done my research and it is not clear what graphics cards belong to one generation or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motherboard is a PCI-Express 1.x generation slot, however [most 2.0 cards are backwards compatible with 1.x slots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_2.0). When you are looking around on the net just check to see if it mentions PCI-Express 1.0, or 2.0, and it ***should*** work with your motherboard.

If the card says PCI-Express 2.1, 3.0, or 4.0 it will definitely **not** work with your motherboard, as they are not backwards compatible with 1.x.

newegg.com can [filter cards](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&Subcategory=48&Description=&Type=&N=100007709&IsNodeId=1&IsPowerSearch=1&srchInDesc=&MinPrice=&MaxPrice=&PropertyCodeValue=696%3A9641&PropertyCodeValue=696%3A33099) to show only cards that are 2.0 or below.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Scott, I nailed down this card: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=14-500-193

According to your answer, this card should work for my PCI-E 1.0 slot. How can I be completely sure? If there's a way know without owning it.

Comment: It says it is 2.0, so it should be ok. I would double check with the motherboard support people that the motherboard is at least PCI-E 1.0a. It looks like it is from the email, but you may want to double check.